# How can I style this php with divs?

Tags: php, html, css, formatting

So I'm trying to style this php with divs but it's not behaving how I'd like. I would like each thumbnail to have the catalog number appear under it. What's the best way to do this? I'm not super clear on how php and css interact yet.

```
  $records = $result->getRecords();

                    foreach ($records as $record){
                        $photo = $record->getField("Photo");
                        $thumbnail = $record->getField("Thumbnail");
                        $cNum = $record->getField("Catalog_Number");


                        echo("<div id=\"image_catalog">"\);
                        echo ("<a href = \"");

                        echo ($photo);
                        echo ("\">");
                        echo ("<img src= \" ");
                        echo ($thumbnail);
                        echo (" \"></a>");

                        echo ("<font color=\"white\">");
                        echo ($cNum);
                        echo ("</font>");
                        echo ("</div>");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo("<div id="image_catalog">")
```

line needs semicolon and escape, like this.

```
echo("<div id=\"image_catalog\">");
```

also add semicolon to last line like so.

```
echo ("</div>");
```

Comment: So! those changes worked in that I stopped getting errors. However, now the images are showing up in a single column instead of extending across the page. How can I format this into rows with the catalog number under each image?

Comment: please accept my answer as correct, this is another question. Ask it in another post and others can talk about it.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to link it to your CSS file, then style it through the class or id.